# gRPC Calls from PHP CLI are Stuck

Tags: php, grpc

I am trying to make a gRPC call from PHP to a server that runs on Java. When I do it using simple HTTP requests, I can receive the response successfully. But when I make the call using tinker console, it waits forever. No error that indicates a timeout, nothing. I use php-fpm 7.4 with nginx webserver. I modified /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini for gRPC and protobuf.

Here is an example code block:

```
<?php

// ...

$client = new CameraManagerServiceClient('localhost:16000', [
    'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
]);

$request = new Com\Example\Grpc\Camera;
$request->setId(2);

list($response, $status) = $client->DeleteCamera($request)->wait(); // Stuck at this line.

// ...
```

Comment: "when I make the call using tinker console, it waits forever" -- that may well be the cause. I'd file a bug report. If you really want to ask here, you'd have to extract a [mcve]. The reason is that the cause is obviously not in the code you posted but in the environment it runs in and that needs to be isolated. And yes, that means extracting the relevant code from the tinker console. BTW: Step through this with a debugger in order to find out where it takes a different turn than expected.

Comment: @emre-turan I've a similar (PHP stuck forever) issue. I solved it by un-installing the binary library of GRPC: `apt remove php7.4-grpc` and relying on PHP implementation.

Comment: @IvanButtinoni I installed grpc using pecl, the thing I notice is when I do calls using artisan commands, it works. But if it is artisan console, it is stuck.

Comment: @emre-turan my situation is totally different. I use grpc by Php-Google-client. After installing the ext-grpc (the .so library) the call stuck. But the gRPC is available in php-only implementation. I suggest you to disable the .so library and try the php-only implementation, and check if anything change.

Comment: @IvanButtinoni I have a similar situation - `getStatus()` is stuck. Everything I find is the installation with pecl or building the library manually. Where do I get the "php-only implementation"?

Comment: @iRaS unfortunately I don't remeber (I also check in my old projects) :((

Answer (score 1):

It will be fixed if you set the environment variable `GRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1`

### Update:

After updating to gRPC v1.60.0 the above solution stopped working, one solution I've been using is to create this config file `/var/www/psysh-config.php` with this content:

```php
<?php

return [
    'usePcntl' => false,
];
```

and then run the CLI command with PSYSH_CONFIG environment variable set to the config file location `PSYSH_CONFIG=/var/www/psysh-config.php php artisan tinker`

Setting `pcre.jit=0` on your php.ini file also seems to fix the issue as an alternative, though I wouldn't advise using the above two solutions in a production setting as I've experienced problems like the HTTP server hanging or background workers having noticeably slower performance after modifying these values.